# flink standalone get no metrics to pushgateway for grafana

Tags: apache-flink, grafana, prometheus-pushgateway

I am new to `flink` and have install `yarn` and `flink` on my macbook with M1 pro chip.

To monitor the running of `flink 1.13`, I installed `grafana`，`prometheus`, `pushgateway` the same way I found on the internet posts, and all the web ui looks fine.

Then I changed the `flink-conf.yaml` file as following [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzvlJ.png) and copy the `flink-metrics-prometheus-1.13.6.jar` to the `lib` folder. And restart the flink using `stop-cluster.sh` and `start-cluster.sh`.

However, the `pushgateway` still get no [metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugea5.png)from `flink`???

Can anyone tell how to fix?

Really in a hurry. Many Thankssssss!!!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. I think its quite tricky, should use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

```
metrics.reporter.promgateway.host: 127.0.0.1
```